# Positive lookahead for exclamation mark

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to build a Java regular expression to match "`.jar!`"

The catch is that I don't want the matcher to consume the exclamation mark. I tried using `Pattern.compile("\\.jar(?=!)")` but that failed. As did escaping the exclamation mark.

Can anyone get this to work or is this a JDK bug?

**UPDATE**: I feel like an idiot, `Pattern.compile("\\.jar(?=!)")` does work. I was using Matcher.matches() instead of Matcher.find().

Comment: Don't delete, this is still informative to others whom may make the same mistake.

Comment: http://www.oleswanson.com/images/office/mistakes.jpg  :)

Comment: Fair enough, I'll leave it up for now :)

Comment: For a lot easier and less error-prone regexping with Java I recommend http://myregexp.com/ This site contains an applet for constructing Java regex AND it's also available as a plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your regex works for me (using Sun JDK 1.6.0_02 for Linux):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Regex {
        private static final String text = ".jar!";

        private static final String regex = "\\.jar(?=!)";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
                Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(text);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                        System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group());
                } else {
                        System.out.println("No match.");
                }
        }
}
```

prints:

```
Match: .jar
```

(without the !)

Comment: Your problem might have been that you were using Matcher.matches() instead of .find(), which requires that the entire input pattern matches.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could try boxing it

```
Pattern.compile("\\.jar(?=[!])")
```

<sub>Java must be broken: Perl</sub>

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my @data = qw( .jar .jar! .jarx .jarx! );


my @patterns = (
  "\\.jar(?=!)",
  "\\.jar(?=\\!)",
  "\\.jar(?=[!])",
);


for my $pat ( @patterns ){
  for my $inp ( @data ) {
    if ( $inp =~ /$pat/ ) {
      print "$inp =~ $pat \n";
    }
  }
}
```

->

```
.jar! =~ \.jar(?=!) 
.jar! =~ \.jar(?=\!) 
.jar! =~ \.jar(?=[!])
```

Comment: It isn't semantically any different from the pattern in the question.